# integrals proving equality

Tags: definite-integrals

> Prove that
>   $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = c\int_{a/c}^{b/c} f(cy)\,dy$$

I've tried to use subtitution rule, but I'm afraid I can't do this if f is not continuous.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use substitution. It is legal here.

Comment: can you explain please why it's legal here?

Comment: The substitution $y=x/c$ is differentiable.

Comment: @Unwisdom has explained it.

Answer (score 4):

Substituting $x=g\left(y\right)$ is allowed here under certain conditions
on function $g$ (so not conditions on the integrand $f$). Here you
do that with function $g\left(y\right)=cy$ which is okay if $c\neq0$.

Comment: This really answers the question.  The asker forgot to mention that $c \neq 0$, and you brought this up.  Yes.  This is certainly true.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=cy$. Therefore, $dx=c dy$, and the limits become the desired ones: $a/c$ and $b/c$. Therefore, the integral is:

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = c\int_{a/c}^{b/c} f(cy)\,dy$$

Which is what we wanted.

Comment: does not answer the question.

Comment: @Sabyasachi. Why ? This is correctly proven as long as $c$ is not zero.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the OP did consider the substitution. (S)he isn't sure if it is correct. That explanation is required.

Comment: The OP's confusion regarding the requirement on the continuity of $f$(which is wrong) should also have been cleared up.